# Creating new variable comprised of 2 random samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, shiny

My goal is to have one plot that has 2 bars: 1 for the filtered dataset and 1 more the unfiltered. When I output my plot, I have one wide bar. I believe I need to combine mysample and mysample2 into a new variable and plot that on the x axis. If anyone has a different idea please feel free to let me know, I'm really stuck on how to get this done.[image]

Also, I know x = input$obs is completely wrong, but I didn't know what else to try.

```
filtered = readxl::read_excel("/Filter.xlsx")
unfiltered = readxl::read_excel("/Unfilter.xlsx")
```

UI:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of Observations", value = 550, min = 100, max = 1000),
  plotOutput("filter")
)
```

Server:

```
server = function(input, output) {
  output$filter = renderPlot({
    mysample = filtered[sample(1:nrow(filtered), input$obs,
                            replace=FALSE),]
     mysample2 = unfiltered[sample(1:nrow(unfiltered), input$obs,
                            replace=FALSE),]


  ggplot(NULL, aes_string(x = input$obs)) +
    geom_col(data = mysample, aes(y = Net_Return)) +
    geom_col(data = mysample2, aes(y = Net_Return)) +

    labs(y = "Net Return") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)     
 })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right; you need a single data frame with both the filtered and unfiltered data. I think this code for your server function will work, but I'm not sure why you were using `aes_string()`,...

```
server = function(input, output) {
  output$filter = renderPlot({
    mysample = filtered[sample(1:nrow(filtered), input$obs,
                            replace=FALSE),]
     mysample2 = unfiltered[sample(1:nrow(unfiltered), input$obs,
                            replace=FALSE),]
    tbl = bind_rows(filtered = mysample, unfiltered = mysample2,
     .id="type")


  ggplot(tbl, aes(x = type)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = `Net Return`)) +
    labs(y = "Net Return") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)     
 })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One of the bars is higher than the other. Do you know how to get them on the same baseline?

Comment: can you post an image of what it looks like?